# bulk insert isn't working reading .txt file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using bulk insert to read a text file into a SQL Server table. I keep getting the same error when I try using bulk insert, even though if I take the first line of the text file, and copy the values into a plain old insert into statement, everything works. My database, stop_times, is setup as follows:

```
train_num int,
arrival_time time,
dept_time time,
station_name varchar(50),
seq_num, int
```

My .txt file has the following format

```
 101,'04:30:00','04:30:00','San Jose',1
 101,'04:35:00','04:35:00','Santa Clara',2
 101,'04:40:00','04:40:00','Lawrence',3
```

Running

```
 bulk insert dbo.stop_times
 from 'C:\Users\amanda\Desktop\stop_times1.txt'
 with(
     FIELDTERMINATOR=','
 )
```

Gives me

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified    codepage) for row 1, column 1 (train_num).
>   Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified  codepage) for row 2, column 2 (arrival_time).
>   Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified  codepage) for row 3, column 2 (arrival_time).

etc

However, copying and pasting the first row into

```
insert into stop_times(train_num, arrival_time, dept_time, station_name, seq_num)
values (101, '04:30:00', '04:30:00', 'San Jose', 1);
```

works. I feel like I'm missing something totally obvious in the bulk insert function, but am clueless.

Comment: Have a look at format files http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 bulk insert dbo.stop_times
 from 'C:\Users\amanda\Desktop\stop_times1.txt'
 with(
     FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
 )
```

IF you have column names in 1st row  u need to do something like this

```
 bulk insert dbo.stop_times
 from 'C:\Users\amanda\Desktop\stop_times1.txt'
 with(
     FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
     FIRSTROW = 2

 )
```

Comment: **TIP** and make sure the file you are trying to import is not open anywhere else before you run this query

Comment: I've made sure the file is closed, and reran it with the ROWTERMINATOR. I still get those errors (even tried '\r\n' for the ROWTERMINATOR)

Comment: Have you tried doing it with only '\n' and could you please tell me what are the data types for the columns where you are trying to insert these records and approximately how many records there are in that .txt files.

Comment: From left to right the data types are int, time, time, varchar(50) and int. There are 2275 lines in the text file. Just using '\n'. So, I tried reading a single row in just now, and got rid of the quotes around the times. Was that the issue? For some reason I thought the times should have quotes around them.

Comment: its because wwhen you bulk insert data with 'your_data' into time column sql server treats it as string data type varchar/nvarchar thats why it was throwing an error.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Now I have the problem of the time data type not handling times after 23:59, but that's another SO post in another time